# Вопрос по верстке коллапса

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Имеется вот такой блок:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.apps-categories {
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 43px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.categories-descr {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #191919;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.app-category-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #191919;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.app-category-btn:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.show-categories-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="apps-categories">
  <p class="categories-descr">Related Categories:</p>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  <a class="app-category-btn" href="#close">GPS Trackers</a>
  
  <a class="show-categories-btn" href="#close">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Как он должен работать: при ресайзе окна браузера кнопки категорий приложений "спрыгивают" вниз, их не должно быть видно, блок при этом имеет прежнюю высоту. Кнопка коллапса показывается только в тех случаях, когда одна из кнопок приложений спрыгивает вниз и служит для того, чтобы раскрыть блок, показав все спрыгнувшие кнопки приложений.

Собственно, не знаю как мне это организовать, особенно в той части, которая предполагает появление кнопки коллапса при спрыгивании первой кнопки категории приложения.

Прошу помочь по мере возможности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVYBxE) решения вашей задачи, количество кнопок, высоту открывания списка придется прописать:

```js
$(function(){
  myRes();
$(window).on('resize',myRes);
  
  function myRes(){
    var len = $('div > div').length;
  var width = $('div > div').css('width');

  if (parseFloat($('div#cont').css('width')) < len*parseFloat(width) ) {
       
      $('#arrow').show();
  } else {
    $('#arrow').hide();
      }
  }
  
  $('#arrow').click(function(){
    if($('#cont').css('height') == '20px'){
      $('#cont').css('height','40px');  
    } else {
      $('#cont').css('height','20px');
    }
    
  });
  
  
  
});
```

```css
span {
    background: green url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-16.png") no-repeat scroll right center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 16px;
}

#cont {
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 35%;
  float:left;
}
div > div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  float:left;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<span id="arrow"></span>
```

Comment: Последовал вашему совету, но работает, почему-то, частично: кнопка с иконкой появляется только при спрыгивании 4-й (и далее) по счету кнопки "app-category-btn".

Comment: Забыл добавить линк на кодпен: http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/LGojMX?editors=1010

Comment: @Игорь потому что у меня нет надписи "Related Categories:", вы ее ширину не учли, наугад добавил 200 и заработало http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxgpwm?editors=1010 Во втором ответе mJeevas показал логику изменения высоты открывающегося меню. Возьмите оттуда.

Answer (score 2):

Для опеределения необходимости добавления коллапса придется пользоваться javascript/jquery.

Положите внутрь .apps-categories еше одну обертку для кнопочек.
Высота этих кнопочек должна быть фиксированной и должна равняться высоте .app-categories.

В чем трюк: При ресайзе окна и соскакивании одной из кнопочек вниз, высота внутренней обертки должна увеличиться/увеличиться вдвое(если сверстать правильно) и скрыться за внешней оберткой .app-categories. Вам необходимо сравнить эти эти две высоты.

```
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="statuses">
  <div class="">Высота box-outer: <span class="box-outer-height"></span></div>
  <div class="">Высота box-inner: <span class="box-inner-height"></span></div>
  <div class="">Добавляем коллапс: <span class="collapse-status"></span></div>
</div>
```

-

```
.box-outer{height: 50px; overflow: hidden; background: red}
.item{display: inline-block; height: 50px; background: blue; color: #fff;}
```

-

```
function calcSize(){
  var box_outer_height = $('.box-outer').height();
  var box_inner_height = $('.box-inner').height();

  $('.box-outer-height').text(box_outer_height);
  $('.box-inner-height').text(box_inner_height);

  if(box_inner_height > box_outer_height){
    $('.collapse-status').text('Да');
  }else{
    $('.collapse-status').text('Нет');
  }
}

$(function(){
  calcSize();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    calcSize();
  });
});
```

-

http://jsbin.com/sujixojesa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `$(window).resize(calcSize(););` тут ошибка, лишняя точка с запятой. У вас всегда `добавляем коллапс - нет`.